# Generate Class and add Annotation in creation eclipse wizard

Tags: java, eclipse

In the below image (eclipse class creation wizard), I can specify package name, class name, parent class or Interface, but there is no way to add annotation,is there any way to add the annotation to class automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With native Eclipse, I think that it is not possible.
A bypassing solution would be to create your own Eclipse templates (Java/Editor/Templates).
As soon as the class is created, you apply the template with your shortcut template such as "test" for adding a JUnit Test annotation.